# Matrix accessing and multiplication optimization for cpu

Tags: java, c++, optimization, matrix, intrinsics

Im making some intrinsic optimized matrix-wrapper in java(with help of JNI). Needing affirmation of this, **can you give some hints about matrix optimizations?** What Im going to implement is:

Matrix can be represented as four set of buffers/arrays, one for horizontal accessing, one for vertical accessing, one for diagonal access and a command buffer to compute elements of matrix only when needed. Here is an illustration.

```
Matrix signature: 

0  1  2  3  

4  5  6  7

8  9  1  3

3  5  2  9

First(hroizontal) set: 
horSet[0]={0,1,2,3} horSet[1]={4,5,6,7} horSet[2]={8,9,1,3} horSet[3]={3,5,2,9}

Second(vertical) set:
verSet[0]={0,4,8,3} verSet[1]={1,5,9,5} verSet[2]={2,6,1,2} verSet[3]={3,7,3,9}

Third(optional) a diagonal set:
diagS={0,5,1,9} //just in case some calculation needs this

Fourth(calcuation list, in a "one calculation one data" fashion) set:
calc={0,2,1,3,2,5} --->0 means multiply by the next element
                       1 means add the next element
                       2 means divide by the next element
                       so this list means
                       ( (a[i]*2)+3 ) / 5  when only a[i] is needed.
Example for fourth set: 
A.mult(2),   A.sum(3),  A.div(5), A.mult(B)
(to list)   (to list)  (to list) (calculate *+/ just in time when A is needed )
 so only one memory access for four operations.
 loop start
 a[i] = b[i] * ( ( a[i]*2) +3 ) / 5  only for A.mult(B)
 loop end
```

So as seen above, when one needs to access column elements,second sets provide contiguous accesses. No leaps taken. Same thing achieved with first set for horizontal access.

This should give some things easier and some things harder:

```
 Easier: 
 **Matrix transpozing operation. 
 Just swapping the pointers horSet[x] and verSet[x] is enough.

 **Matrix * Matrix multiplication.
 One matrix gives one of its horizontal set and other matrix gives vertical buffer.
 Dot product of these must be highly parallelizable for intrinsics/multithreading.
 If the multiplication order is inverse, then horizontal and verticals are switched.

 **Matrix * vector multiplication.
 Same as above, just a vector can be taken as horizontal or vertical freely.

 Harder:
 ** Doubling memory requirement is bad for many cases.
 ** Initializing a matrix takes longer.
 ** When a matrix is multiplied from left, needs an update vertical-->horizontal
 sets if its going to be multiplied from right after.(same for opposite)
 (if a tranposition is taken between, this does not count)


 Neutral:
 ** Same matrix can be multiplied with two other matrices to get two different
 results such as A=A*B(saved in horizontal sets)   A=C*A(saved in vertical sets)
 then A=A*A gives   A*B*C*A(in horizontal) and C*A*A*B (in vertical) without
 copying A. 

 ** If a matrix always multiplied from left or always from right, every access
 and multiplication will not need update and be contiguous on ram.

 ** Only using horizontals before transpozing, only using verticals after, 
 should not break any rules.
```

Main purpose is having a matrix of (multiple of 8, multiple of 8) size and applying avx intrinsics with multiple threads( each tread works on a set concurrently).

I have achieved only vector * vector dotproduct. **I will go into this if you masters of programming give a direction.**

The dotproduct I wrote(with intrinsics) is 6x faster than a loop-unrolled version(which is two times as fast of multiplication one by one), also stucks at memory bandwidth cap when multithreading enabled in wrapper (8x --> uses nearly 20GB/s which is close to my ddr3's limit) Tried opencl already and it is kind of slow for cpu, but great for gpu.

Thank you.

**Edit:** How would a "Block Matrix" buffer perform? When multiplying big matrices, small patches are multiplied in a special way and cache is probably used for main memory access reduction. But this would need even more updates between matrix multiplications between vertical-horizontal-diagonal and this block.

Comment: One way to obtain highly optimized matrix algebra code is using Expression Templates condensing the whole stuff in specialized methods without carrying out each specific step.

Comment: What about using sub-matrices and some linear algebra to use cache more(block algorithm)?  Is this acceptable for the vertical&horizontal buffer approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several libraries use [Expression Templates](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_Templates) to enable the application of very specific, optimized functions for a cascade of matrix operations.

[The C++ Programming Lanuage](http://books.google.de/books?id=riM_PgAACAAJ&dq=The+C%2B%2B+Programming+Language&hl=de&sa=X&ei=qlDnUeWmGYjFtQa14oDoCA&redir_esc=y) also has a short chapter about "Fused Operations" (29.5.4, 4th Edition).

This enables concatenation of statements à la:

```
M = A*B.transp(); // where M, A, B are matrices
```

You'll want to have 3 classes in this case:

```
class Matrix;

class Transposed
{
public:
  Transposed(Matrix &matrix) : m_matrix(matrix) {}
  Matrix & obj (void) { return m_matrix; }
private:
  Matrix & m_matrix;
};

class MatrixMatrixMulTransPosed
{
public:
  MatrixMatrixMulTransPosed(Matrix &matrix, Transposed &trans) 
    : m_matrix(matrix), m_transposed(trans.obj()) {}
  Matrix & matrix (void) { return m_matrix; }
  Matrix & transposed (void) { return m_transposed; }
private:
  Matrix & m_matrix;
  Matrix & m_transposed;
};

class Matrix
{
  public:
    MatrixMatrixMulTransPosed operator* (Transposed &rhs)
    { 
      return MatrixMatrixMulTransPosed(*this, rhs); 
    }

    Matrix& operator= (MatrixMatrixMulTransPosed &mmtrans)
    {
      // Actual computation goes here and is stored in this.
      // using mmtrans.matrix() and mmtrans.transposed()
    }
};
```

You can advance this concept to be able to have a spcialized function for every computation that is critcal by any mean.

Comment: Im testing vector x vector, it multiplies two 64M-element vectors in 45 milliseconds(1.4GHz fx8150). Would you expect a similar performance from matrix multiplications too?(such as multiplying two matrices of 256x512 and 512 x 512 sizes)

Comment: I'm not a linear algebra guru but I guess a "plain" matrix multiplication will suffer from a lot of cache misses in case of strided data access but you are obviously willing to account for that via a second data set. You should, nevertheless be careful to avoid introducing any artificial bottlenecks since both representations need to match and you'll need to have updating routines.

Comment: Okay, just done first multiplication. On a single core of 1.4GHz fx8150 with 1024x1024 matrix, multiplication took 1.3 second. Do you think this got any cache miss?

Comment: When I increase the problem size to 4096x4096 (64 times work) and increase cpu frequency to 4.0GHz and enable parallelization by Parallel.For of C#(yes I migrated the code to C# with has easy parallelization), multiplication took 14.9 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively equivalent to cacheing the transposition.  It sounds like you intend to do this eagerly; I'd just compute the transposition only when it is needed and remember it in case it is needed again.  That way, if you never need it then it never gets computed.