# Cache-friendly optimization: Object oriented matrix multiplication and in-function tiled matrix multiplication

Tags: c#, c++, caching, optimization, matrix-multiplication

After writing a matrix class that represents whole matrix in two 1D-buffers using  [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711686/matrix-accessing-and-multiplication-optimization-for-cpu) , I've reached the matrix maltiplication part in my project and inclined to some cache-friendly-optimizations now. Stumbled upon two options(question is in lower part of this page):

1)Selecting blocked/tiled sub-matrices just in the multiplication time.

- Done in c++ DLL function, so no function overhead.
- Since the code will be more complex, additional optimizations will be harder to apply.

2)Building a matrix class from sub matrix classes(smaller patches) so multiplication is generally done on sub-matrix classes.

- Object oriented approach leaves space for additional optimizations for sub-matrices.
- Object headers and padding behavior of C# can help overcome critical strides?
- Function overhead can be a problem after calling it many times instead of a few times.

Example matrix multiplication: C=A.B

```
 A
 1 2 3 4   is used as  1 2    3 4  
 4 3 4 2               4 3    4 2  
 1 3 1 2                           
 1 1 1 2               1 3    1 2  
                       1 1    1 2


 B
 1 1 1 1  --->         1 1    1 1
 1 1 1 1               1 1    1 1
 1 1 1 1 
 1 1 1 1               1 1    1 1
                       1 1    1 1


 Multiplication:       1 2 * 1 1   +   3 4 * 1 1    ==>  upper-left tile of result
                       4 3   1 1       4 2   1 1  


                       same for the upper-right of result

                       1 3 * 1 1   +   1 2 * 1 1    ==> lower left tile of result
                       1 1   1 1       1 2   1 1

                       same for lower-right tile of result

        Multiplication is O(n³) but summation is O(n²).
```

**Question:** Has anyone tried both(functional and object oriented) and made performance comparisons? Right now, my naive multiplication without any of these cache targeted optimizations, takes:

```
 Matrix Size   Single Threaded Time    Multithreaded Time
 * 128x128   :     5    ms                 1ms-5ms(time sample error is bigger)
 * 256x256   :     25   ms                 7     ms
 * 512x512   :     140  ms                 35    ms
 * 1024x1024 :     1.3  s                  260   ms
 * 2048x2048 :     11.3 s                  2700  ms 
 * 4096x4096 :     88.1 s                  24    s
 * 8192x8192 :     710  s                  177   s

 Giga-multiplications of variables per second
               Single threaded         Multithreaded           Multi/single ratio               
 * 128x128   :     0.42                    2.0 - 0.4               ?
 * 256x256   :     0.67                    2.39                   3.67x  
 * 512x512   :     0.96                    3.84                   4.00x
 * 1024x1024 :     0.83                    3.47                   4.18x
 * 2048x2048 :     0.76                    3.18                   4.18x
 * 4096x4096 :     0.78                    2.86                   3.67x
 * 8192x8192 :     0.77                    3.09                   4.01x
```

(average results for 1.4GHz fx8150 with avx-optimized code using 32-bit floats)(c++ avx-intrinsics in dll functions within Parallel.For() of visual studio C#)

Which size of matrices above could be suffered from cache misses, critical strides and other bad things? Do you know how can I get performance counters of those using intrinsics?

Thans for your time.

**Edit:** Inlining optimization within DLL:

```
 Matrix Size   Single Threaded Time    Multithreaded Time           Multi/Single radio
 * 128x128   :  1     ms(%400)          390us avrage in 10k iterations(6G mult /s)
 * 256x256   :  12    ms(%108 faster)   2     ms   (%250 faster)         6.0x
 * 512x512   :  73    ms(%92 faster)    15    ms   (%133 faster)         4.9x
 * 1024x1024 :  1060  ms(%22 faster)    176   ms   (%48 faster)          6.0x
 * 2048x2048 :  10070 ms(%12 faster)    2350  ms   (%15 faster)          4.3x
 * 4096x4096 :  82.0  s(%7 faster)      22    s    (%9 faster)           3.7x
 * 8192x8192 :  676   s(%5 faster)      174   s    (%2 faster)           4.1x
```

After the inlining, the shadowed performance of smaller multiplications become visible.
There is still DLL-function-C# overhead. 1024x1024 case seems to be starting point of cache-misses. While work is increased by only seven times, the execution time is increased to fifteen times.

**Edit:**: Going to try Strassen's algorithm for 3-layers deep with object oriented approach this week. Main matrix will be composed of 4 sub matrices. Then they will be composed of 4 sub-subs each. Then they will be composed of 4 sub-sub-subs each. This should give nearly (8/7)*(8/7)*(8/7)= +%50 speedup. If it works, will convert DLL-function to patch-optimized one which will use more cache.

Comment: Look at the number of operations per second (or similar) to figure out where your caches start to affect the calculation - I haven't done exact math for your samples, but just looking at it and making the math in my head (fallible, no doubt about it) says that there is a bigger step for 2K x 2K to 4K x 4K than the others (both in single and multicore variants, which is hardly surprising).

Comment: Okay, calculated multiplications per second, 512x512 is best performing. But the greatest leap is between 256x256 and 512x512 and is positive, this must be function overhead and the greatest fall is between 512x512 and 1024x1024. Does this mean, 4M elements of two matrices are 16M and that does not fit even in L3?

Comment: Yes, does sound like your smaller ones suffer from function overhead. I have no idea what size caches your processor has, but yes, there sill be a big drop-off when going over the cache-edge. I would actually expect it to be more noticeable than what your results show - since the actual memory throughput will be quite a lot worse - but I suspect you are not hitting the worst case (yet?).

Comment: The 1024x1024 part uses more than 20GB/s which is very hard for my 1866MHz duad channel ddr3 ram. A fraction may be coming from cache usage. L1=64 Kilo Bytes shared per 2 cores, L2=2MB per two cores, L3=8MB shared.

Comment: 1024 x 1024 x sizeof(double) = 8MB. So at that point you are obviously not going to fit both A and B matrices in any of the caches  - however, with 4 cores, you should be able to fit most in the L2 caches.

Comment: The function in the dll also uses another function in the same dll frequently. Should I inline it ?

Comment: Have you checked if the compiler inlines it already? Most modern compilers will do that if it makes sense. I can't say without understanding the code.

Comment: Its msvc and I did not choose any special flags. Only target machine x64 and avx code generation(chose it for intrinsics)

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the generated code, does it inline or not?

Comment: Im searching the assembly output flag but cannot find.

Comment: Under "listing files" or some such.

Comment: Okay, it was not inlining so I inlined the core function. That clearly speed-up by at least %50 for 1024x1024 case.  256 ---> 512 ---->1024 steps were bigger than others. The sudden performance drop for 1024x1024(and bigger ones) must be the cache issue you mentioned.

Comment: If I make eight 512x512 sub-matrix classes into one to get a 1024x1024 one(multiplication will take eight smaller multiplications), that would take 120-140ms instead of 176ms. Sum of sub results is lower complexity than O(n^3). Maybe even using 256x256 would give good speed up for object oriented choice. I could try in-DLL optimization of 32x32 patches to get a hybrid-optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying Strassen's Algorithm for just one layer(such as four of 256x256 as 512x512) as an object-oriented approach(the super class is `Strassen` and the submatrices are `matrix` classes):

```
 Matrix Size   Single Threaded Time    Multithreaded Time           Multi/Single radio
 * 128x128   :  **%50 slowdown**        **slowdown**              
 * 256x256   :  **%30 slowdown**        **slowdown**         
 * 512x512   :  **%10 slowdown**        **slowdown**            
 * 1024x1024 :  540   ms(%96 faster)    130   ms   (%35 faster)     4.15     
 * 2048x2048 :  7500  ms(%34 faster)    1310  ms   (%79 faster)     5.72    
 * 4096x4096 :  70.2  s(%17 faster)     17    s    (%29 faster)     4.13
 * 6144x6144 :          x               68    s               
 * 8192x8192 :  outOfMemoryException    outOfMemoryException
```

The overhead between DLL-function and C# is still in effect so small matrices could not get faster. But when there is a speedup, its always more than 8/7(%14) because using smaller chunks is better for cache usage.

Will write a benchmark class that repeatedly tests for different leaf sizes of Stressen's Algorithm versus naive one to find the critical size. (for my system, it is 512x512).

Superclass will recursively build the sub-matrix tree until it reaches the 512x512 size and will use naive algorithm for 512x512 nodes. Then in the DLL-function, a patched/blocking algorithm(will add this next week) will make it some more faster. But I dont know how to select proper size of patch because I dont know how to get cache-line size of cpu. Will search for that after recursive Strassen is done.

My implementation of Strassen's Algorithm needs five times more memory(working on it).

Edit: some of recursivity is done, updating the table as resuts come.

```
 Matrix Size   Single Threaded Time    Multithreaded Time           
 * 2048x2048 :  x                       872     ms  average(double layer)    
 * 2560x2560 :  x                       1527    ms  average(double layer)
```

Parallelized the tree parsing, decreased memory footprint and introduced full recursivity:

```
 Matrix Size   Single Threaded Time    Multithreaded Time                         m/s
 * 1024x1024 :  547   ms               123     ms  average(single layer)          4.45x
 * 2048x2048 :  3790  ms               790     ms  average(double layer)          4.79x
 * 4096x4096 :  26.4  s                5440    ms  average(triple layer)          4.85x
 * 8192x8192 :  185   s                38      s   average(quad layer)            4.87x
 * 8192x8192(4GHz):   x                15      s   average(quad layer)            4.87x
```

Multiplications per second (x10^9):

```
 Matrix Size   Single Threaded         Multithreaded                          
 * 1024x1024 :  1.71                   7.64     (single layer)          
 * 2048x2048 :  1.73                   8.31     (double layer)          
 * 4096x4096 :  1.74                   8.45     (triple layer)         
 * 8192x8192 :  1.74                   8.48     (quad layer)           
 * 8192x8192(4GHz):   x                21.49    (quad layer)           
 Strassen's cpu flops is multiplied by 7/8 for each layer.
```

Just found out that using a similarly priced gpu can do 8kx8k under 1 second using opencl.